# Issue with increasing the root partition from the swap

Tags: partitioning, gparted, swap

I have an issue with increase the size of my root partition. I have ElementaryOS Luna, and while installing it asked me how much space I want to use. I choosed 15 GB for it, because I want to use this as an alternative system. The issue is that after the installation was complete, I found out that my root partition is only 7 GB big, and SWAP is 8 GB which is useless cuz I have 8 GB of RAM. Now I want to shrink the swap and increase the size of my root partition, so I booted the LiveCD and used GParted. I shrinked the swap without any problems, but now I cant add that free space to any partition. I also turned Swap off. I would add a picture, but I need at least 10 reputation to post images ( Stupid )

Its also worth mentioning that in Gparted its showing my partition in a different way. I would post an image BUT I CANT, so I need to write it down.
Its something like this

- [Pointing arrow down] /dev/sda4 Extended
- /dev/sda5 ntfs
- /dev/sda6 ext4 (Which is my main partition)
- /dev/sda7 linux-swap
- unallocated

Picture:

[image]

Comment: A picture would indeed be very helpful, can't you upload it somewhere else and give me the link ?

Comment: Here you go! http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/5/zchq.png/

Comment: Looks perfect ! tnx, my answer is in the answer-block :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good shot! :-)  now try this:

1. swap off
2. move the swap as far as possible into the unallocated area
3. commit the change

   if this fails, then stop and report it here.
4. grow your ext4 partition
5. commit the change

   report if it worked or where it failed.

Comment: I cannot grow my ext4 partition regardless of how I shrink the swap partition. I could shrink my swap to total 1 MB.

Comment: You could move swap to the right though...good. Now I think that you cannot change the ext4 partition because it is mounted. If you can run gparted from windows (yes there is a windows version) it will probably work.

Comment: I checked the google and official Gparted website and there is no windows version. There is only livecd version, but its the same as Ubuntu or Luna livecd.

Comment: Live CD is also good...boot from it, delete the swap completely. Commit. grow ext4. add swap. Commit.

Comment: Finally! Deleting Swap completly helped! Now I can resize the root partition. Many Thanks!